# NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I created this app to display users or owners of nodes, but now when I try to log in, the application fails with the message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass):
```

Here is the line of code that the error is pointing at

users_controllers.rb

```
 def authenticate
    if params[:authentication] and authenticate = params[:authentication] and authenticate[:email].length > 0 and authenticate[:password].length > 0
      username = authenticate[:email]
      password = authenticate[:password]

      super_user = User.find(TheChosenOne.first.user_id) # This is the problematic line
      if username == super_user.email
        if Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password) == TheChosenOne.first.password
          session[:user_id] = super_user.id
          redirect_to controller: :nodes, action: :list
        else
          redirect_to controller: :users, action: :login, alert: 'invalid_credentials' and return
        end
      else
        ret_result = nil
        command = Thread.new do
          ret_result  = `cd #{Rails.root}/Auth/src/; java AuthorizationService '#{username}' '#{password}'`
        end
        command.join

        if !ret_result.include? "true"
          redirect_to controller: :users, action: :login, alert: 'invalid_credentials' and return
        end

        user = User.find_by_email(username)
        if !User.exists?(user)
          user = User.create({email: username})
        end
```

I am not sure whether I need to created a user_id method in the user model? This does not seem  to make a lot of sense to me. Please I will appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you

Comment: your session variable is not initiated. please show us your entire code

Comment: Can you verify that `TheChosenOne.first` is non-null? Using a debugger tool like `pry` will go a long way.

Comment: Unrelated to your initial question, but you have there an unauthenticated remote code execution vulnerability with your shellout. By using a username such as `whatever'; /path/to/evil; echo '` I can execute whatever command I want on your server. Also, you should not use unsalted SHA1 to store your passwords. Use [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) instead.

Comment: I can also skip the authentication entirely with any random username and a password such as `whatever'; echo 'true`. You might want to use [Shellwords.shellescape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-escape) for all arguments or use a safer method for your shellouts.

Comment: As @maxpleaner suggests, `TheChosenOne.first` is returning nil

Comment: Thank you to everyone that contributed: @CancluCostin,   I am grateful for your contributions. The app is now back online. Interestingly, I did NOT have to alter the line of code that I thought was responsible for the app failure!

Comment: Thank you to everyone that contributed:@Max pleaner !) I am grateful for your contributions. The app is now back online. Interestingly, I did NOT have to alter the line of code that I thought was responsible for the app failure!

Comment: Thank you to: @HolgerJust (Your point about the security concern is noted!) I am grateful for your contributions. The app is now back online. Interestingly, I did NOT have to alter the line of code that I thought was responsible for the app failure!

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear that `TheChosenOne.first` is `nil`, and `nil` does not have a `#user_id` method.

I'm assuming your question basically is: How do I find out *why* `TheChosenOne.first` is `nil`?

We'll use `pry`, `byebug`, and `rails console` to debug this. First, make sure `pry` is installed in your Gemfile, if not already:

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'       # pry integrated with byebug
  gem 'pry-rails'        # integrates pry with rails
end
```

First `bundle install`, then start `rails console`:

```sh
% rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 91323
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.2)
[1] pry(main)>
```

You should be able to execute `TheChosenOne.first` and confirm it's `nil`:

```rb
[1] pry(main)> TheChosenOne.first
=> nil
```

`pry` has a nice debugging feature to inspect the source code of a method with `$`:

```rb
[2] pry(main)> $ TheChosenOne.first

From: /myrails/app/models/the_chosen_one.rb:2:
Owner: #<Class:TheChosenOne>
Visibility: public
Signature: first()
Number of lines: 3

def self.first
  nil
end
```

I've created a dummy example where `TheChosenOne.first` just returns `nil`, but you should see how it's implemented and where it's defined. Use that information to dig one level deeper to find out why it's returning `nil`, because it appears as if it shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you, I am grateful for your contributions. The app is now back online. Interestingly, I did NOT have to alter the line of code that I thought was responsible for the app failure!